# How to recursively construct an JSON hierarchy from a NodeList?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Given the following input:

```
<dl>
  <dt>
    <h3>Title A</h3>
    <dl>
      <dt>
        <h3>Title A- A</h3>
        <dl>
          <dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt>
          <dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt>
        </dl>
      </dt>
      <dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt>
      <dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt>
      <dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt>
      <dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt>
      <dt>
        <h3>Title B- A</h3>
        <dl>
          <dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt>
          <dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt>
        </dl>
      </dt>
      <dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt>
    </dl>
  </dt>
</dl>
```

I want to build an JSON object based on the above input:

```
{
  "title": "Title A",
  "children": [
    {
      "title": "Title A- A",
      "children": [
        {"title": "Item"},
        {"title": "Item"}
      ]
    },
    {"title": "Item"},
    {"title": "Item"},
    {"title": "Item"},
    {"title": "Item"},
    {
      "title": "Title B- A",
      "children": [
        {"title": "Item"},
        {"title": "Item"}
      ]
    },
    {"title": "Item"}
  ]
}
```

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
function buildTree(node) {
    if (!node) return [];
    const h3 = node.querySelector('h3') || node.querySelector('a');
    let result = {
        title: h3.innerText,
        children: []
    };
    const array = [...node.querySelectorAll('dl')];
    if (array) {
        result.children = array.map(el => buildTree(el.querySelector('dt')));
    }
    return result;
}
```

The result I'm getting is different from what I expect, Here's the result I am getting:

```
{
  "title": "Title A",
  "children": [
    {
      "title": "Title A",
      "children": [
        {
          "title": "Title A- A",
          "children": [
            {
              "title": "Item A- A 1",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "Item A- A 1",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "title": "Title B- A 1",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Title A- A",
      "children": [
        {
          "title": "Item A- A 1",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Item A- A 1",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "title": "Title B- A 1",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

seems that some data are not there, Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: please note you are misusing `dl`. a term, `dt`, should be adjacent to its definition, `dd`. `dl` can be nested, but only in another `dd`. if absolutely necessary, an element such as `div` can wrap a `dt`/`dd` pair. [read the docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl).

Comment: @Thankyou The input is generated by Microsoft Edge, It's basically structure for exported Favourites (Bookmarks) as HTML

Comment: Sirwan, That's not surprising ‍♀️ Microsoft has a reputation for [not complying with standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Microsoft)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fix html**

First I would remark that you are misusing `dl`. From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) -

> The HTML `<dl>` element represents a description list. The element encloses a list of groups of terms (specified using the `<dt>` element) and descriptions (provided by `<dd>` elements) ...

Here's what the correct use of `dl`, `dt`, and `dd` would look like -

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Title 1</dt>
  <dd>  
    <dl>
      <dt>Title 1.1</dt>
      <dd><a href="#">Item 1.1.1</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Item 1.1.2</a></dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item 1.3</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item 1.4</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item 1.5</a></dd>
  <dd>
    <dl>
      <dt>Title 1.6</dt>    
      <dd><a href="#">Item 1.6.1</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Item 1.6.2</a></dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item 1.7</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Notice it matches the expected shape of your output -

```js
{
  "title": "Title 1",
  "children": [
    {
      "title": "Title 1.1",
      "children": [
        {"title": "Item 1.1.1"},
        {"title": "Item 1.1.2"}
      ]
    },
    {"title": "Item 1.2"},
    {"title": "Item 1.3"},
    {"title": "Item 1.4"},
    {"title": "Item 1.5"},
    {
      "title": "Title 1.6",
      "children": [
        {"title": "Item 1.6.1"},
        {"title": "Item 1.6.2"}
      ]
    },
    {"title": "Item 1.7"}
  ]
}
```

---

**fromHtml**

If you are not willing (or able) to change the input html as described above, please see Scott's wonderful answer. To write a program for the proposed html, I would break it into two parts. First we write `fromHtml` with a simple recursive form -

```js
function fromHtml (e)
{ switch (e?.tagName)
  { case "DL":
      return Array.from(e.childNodes, fromHtml).flat()
    case "DD":
      return [ Array.from(e.childNodes, fromHtml).flat() ]
    case "DT":
    case "A":
      return e.textContent
    default:
      return []
   }
}

fromHtml(document.querySelector('dl'))
```

Which gives us this intermediate format -

```js
[
  "Title 1",
  [
    "Title 1.1",
    [ "Item 1.1.1" ],
    [ "Item 1.1.2" ]
  ],
  [ "Item 1.2" ],
  [ "Item 1.3" ],
  [ "Item 1.4" ],
  [ "Item 1.5" ],
  [
    "Title 1.6",
    [ "Item 1.6.1" ],
    [ "Item 1.6.2" ]
  ],
  [ "Item 1.7" ]
]
```

---

**applyLabels**

Following that, I would write a separate `applyLabels` function which adds the `title` and `children` labels you require -

```js
const applyLabels = ([ title, ...children ]) =>
  children.length
    ? { title, children: children.map(applyLabels) }
    : { title }
  
const result =
  applyLabels(fromHtml(document.querySelector('dl')))
```

```js
{
  "title": "Title 1",
  "children": [
    {
      "title": "Title 1.1",
      "children": [
        {"title": "Item 1.1.1"},
        {"title": "Item 1.1.2"}
      ]
    },
    {"title": "Item 1.2"},
    {"title": "Item 1.3"},
    {"title": "Item 1.4"},
    {"title": "Item 1.5"},
    {
      "title": "Title 1.6",
      "children": [
        {"title": "Item 1.6.1"},
        {"title": "Item 1.6.2"}
      ]
    },
    {"title": "Item 1.7"}
  ]
}
```

I might suggest one final change, which guarantees all nodes in the output have a uniform shape, `{ title, children }`. It's a change worth noting because in this case `applyLabels` is easier to write *and* it behaves better -

```js
const applyLabels = ([ title, ...children ]) =>
  ({ title, children: children.map(applyLabels) })
```

Yes, this means that deepest descendants will have an empty `children: []` property, but it makes consuming the data much easier as we don't have to null-check certain properties.

---

**demo**

Expand the snippet below to verify the results of `fromHtml` and `applyLabels` in your own browser -

```js
function fromHtml (e)
{ switch (e?.tagName)
  { case "DL":
      return Array.from(e.childNodes, fromHtml).flat()
    case "DD":
      return [ Array.from(e.childNodes, fromHtml).flat() ]
    case "DT":
    case "A":
      return e.textContent
    default:
      return []
   }
}

const applyLabels = ([ title, ...children ]) =>
  children.length
    ? { title, children: children.map(applyLabels) }
    : { title }
  
const result =
  applyLabels(fromHtml(document.querySelector('dl')))
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Title 1</dt>
  <dd>  
    <dl>
      <dt>Title 1.1</dt>
      <dd><a href="#">Item 1.1.1</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Item 1.1.2</a></dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item 1.3</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item 1.4</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item 1.5</a></dd>
  <dd>
    <dl>
      <dt>Title 1.6</dt>    
      <dd><a href="#">Item 1.6.1</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Item 1.6.2</a></dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item 1.7</a></dd>
</dl>
```

---

**remarks**

I've written hundreds of answers on the topic of recursion and data transformation and yet this is the *first* time I think I've used `.flat` in an essential way. I thought I had a use case in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334751/633183) but Scott's comment took it from me! This answer differs because `domNode.childNodes` is not a true array and so `Array.prototype.flatMap` cannot be used. Thanks for the interesting problem.

Comment: That markup cleanup ( :-) ) makes for a much nicer structure to code against!  Beautiful code, as always.  Using `.children` rather than `.childNodes` should make some things easier.

Comment: how come i never knew about `.children`?! i don't see it documented on [MDN: Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) or [MDN: HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). what is this sorcery?!

Comment: I think it's actually an older format that was kept around in [MDN:ParentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).

Answer (score 2):

You'd better make the decision before recursion:

```js
function buildTree(node) {
  const result = {};
  for (const el of node.children) {
    switch(el.nodeName) {
      case 'H3':
      case 'A':
        result.title = el.innerText;
        result.children = [];
        break;
      case 'DL':
        result.children = buildTree(el);
        break;
      case 'DT':
        result.children.push(buildTree(el));
        break;
      default:
        console.warn(`Unknown node type '${el.nodeName}'`, el);
    }

  }
  return result;
}
```

With this example, I can see you are trying to parse almost equally `DT`s and `DL`s.

Answer (score 2):

This is a clear-cut case for mutual recursion.  This is straightforward to process if we distinguish how to handle a `DL` and how to handle a `DT`.  (As others have pointed out, without any `DD`'s this is an odd structure.)

I added an `id` to the initial `DL` to make it easy to get hold of.  But however you choose to grab this root element, you should be able to just pass it to `handleDl` to get back your structure.

```js
const handleDl = (dl) => 
  [...dl.children]
    .filter (({nodeName}) => nodeName == 'DT')
    .map (handleDt)

const handleDt = (dt) => {
  const kids = [...dt.children]
  const h3 = kids .find (({nodeName}) => nodeName == 'H3')
  const dl = kids .find (({nodeName}) => nodeName == 'DL')
  return h3
    ? {title: h3.textContent, children: handleDl (dl)}
    : {title: dt.textContent}
}

const node = document.getElementById('foo')

console .log (handleDl (node))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 70% !important; top: 30%}
```

```html
<dl id = "foo"><dt><h3>Title A</h3><dl><dt><h3>Title A- A</h3><dl><dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt><dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt></dl></dt><dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt><dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt><dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt><dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt><dt><h3>Title B- A</h3><dl><dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt><dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt></dl></dt><dt><a href="#">Item</a></dt></dl></dt></dl>
```

`handleDl` simply maps `handleDt` over all `DT` children of the node supplied.

`handleDt` is slightly more complicated, because there are two different styles.  We find the first `H3` and the first `DL` among the node's children.  If an `H3` was found, we choose our title from that, and process the `DL` into a children node, using `handleDl`.  If no `H3` was found, we simply report the title based on the current node's text content.  You might have to get more sophisticated in deriving this text, assuming this is a simplification of your actual problem.  But it shouldn't be difficult.

### Update

Using the much more logical structure from @Thankyou, we can write this same style much more simply.  (Note that there are many error paths that aren't checked.  This could do with a dose of `?`-nullish operators... an exercise for the reader.)  This has a similar breakdown as above, but with simpler code.  It is fairly dependent upon that specific structure, where every `DD` has either a single `DL` or a simple HTML wrapper around our title, and every `DL` has one `DT` followed by one or more `DD`s.  But since that is the specified structure of `DL`, this isn't much of a hardship.

```js
const handleDl = (dl) => ({
  title: dl .children [0] .textContent,
  children: [...dl .children] .slice (1) .map (handleDd)
})

const handleDd = (dd) => 
  dd .children [0] .nodeName == "DL"
    ? handleDl (dd .children [0])
    : {title: dd .textContent}

const node = document .querySelector ('dl')

console .log (handleDl (node))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 70% !important; top: 30%}
```

```html
<dl><dt>Title 1</dt><dd><dl><dt>Title 1.1</dt><dd><a href="#">Item 1.1.1</a></dd><dd><a href="#">Item 1.1.2</a></dd></dl></dd><dd><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></dd><dd><a href="#">Item 1.3</a></dd><dd><a href="#">Item 1.4</a></dd><dd><a href="#">Item 1.5</a></dd><dd><dl><dt>Title 1.6</dt><dd><a href="#">Item 1.6.1</a></dd><dd><a href="#">Item 1.6.2</a></dd></dl></dd><dd><a href="#">Item 1.7</a></dd></dl>
```

Comment: answer looks great for the suggested input. however, this is a misuse of `dl` and `dt`. `dl` can be nested but only if it appears in a `dd`. if i'm going to attempt this one, i think i'll fix the input first.

Comment: whoa this problem was so much harder than i anticipated! and especially so if we don't make assumptions about `h3` and `dl` children being present. and the pesky (empty) text nodes are a real bear. any answer using mutual recursion gets my up-vote :D

Comment: @Thankyou: yes, but your markup simplification offers the ability to do much nicer code.  (See the difference between my original and my update!)

Comment: tears of joy streaming down my face. _that_ is more like what i imagined was possible but couldn't quite crack it. you actually figured it out! happy new year, Scott.

Comment: Scott, an [interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65516725/633183) just appeared. i'm not sure exactly what they want and maybe you will have a different interpretation to the question. either way it seems like a fun one.

Answer (score 1):

I think one important part is that querySelector and querySelectorAll are recursive. And could it be that you confused dl and dt, since there are multiple dt's in a dl? Would the following work for you?

```
function buildTree(node) {
    if (!node) return [];
    const h3 = node.querySelector(':scope > h3') || node.querySelector(':scope > a');
    let result = {
        title: h3.innerText,
        children: []
    };
    const array = [...node.querySelectorAll(':scope > dl > dt')];
    result.children = array.map(el => buildTree(el));
    return result;
}
```

you must initially pass a dt node for this to work. (https://jsfiddle.net/52ups6fL/)

Comment: While multiple `<dt>`s in a row are semantically valid, OP’s code still isn’t, because there are no `<dd>`s at all.

Comment: @user4642212 that's true, but I am not sure whether OP has any influence on the structure of the HTML.

Comment: It seems to be working! thanks. btw I didn't know about `:scope` @likle