# How to build a tree array into which / out of which items can be spliced, which only allows arrays of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, tree

So there is a very elegant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65533067/169992) to a similar problem. The problem there was to build an array tree where every array had only 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 items, and *where every item was at the same nesting level*. I formulated this problem without having the entire system in mind (doing rapid prototyping I guess), but the current system I don't think will really work for *deleting items from the middle of the array*, or *adding items into the middle of the array*. Unfortunately.

I need the ability to add/remove items in the middle of the array because this will be used for arrays in bucketed hash tables, or general arrays which items are rapidly added and removed (like managing memory blocks). So I am thinking how to balance that with the desire to have memory block sizes of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 items only. Hence the tree, but I think the tree needs to work slightly differently from the problem posed in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65516725/how-to-incrementally-build-an-array-tree-where-each-array-can-only-have-1-2-4).

What I'm thinking is having a system like follows. Each array in the nested array tree can have 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 items, *but the items don't need to sit at the same level*. The reason for putting items at the same level is because there is a very efficient algorithm for `getItemAt(index)` if they are at the same level. But it has the problem of not allowing efficient inserts/deletes. But I think this can be solved where items in an array are at *different* levels by having each parent array "container" keep track of how many deeply nested children it has. It would essentially keep track of the size of the subtree. Then to find the item with `getItemAt(index)`, you would traverse the top level of the tree, count the top-level tree sizes, and then narrow your search down the tree like that.

In addition, the leaf arrays (which have 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 items each) can have items *removed*, and then you only have to adjust that short array item's positions. So you'd go from this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

...delete `6`, and get this (where `-` is `null`):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, -]
```

Then if you add an item `9` at say position 3, it would result in:

```
[1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

This is nice because say you have a million items array. You now only have to adjust a single array with up to 32 items, rather than shifting a million items.

BUT, it gets a bit complicated when you add an item in the "middle of this tree array", but at the end of a 32-item array. You would first think you would have to shift every single subsequent array. But there is a way to make it so you don't have to do this shifting! Here is one case.

We start here:

```
[
  [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 ,
    9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32],
  [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 ,
    9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
]
```

Now we add an item `90` at the 16th position. We should end up with this, since this array must grow to be 4 in length:

```
[
  [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 ,
    9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 90,
    16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
    24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21],
  [32],
  -,
  [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 ,
    9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
]
```

If we delete `90` now, we would end with this:

```
[
  [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 ,
    9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, - ],
  [32],
  -,
  [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 ,
    9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
]
```

Basically, it is minimizing the changes that are made. To `getByIndex(index)` it would work like this, with more metadata on the arrays:

```
{
  size: 64,
  list: [
    {
      size: 31,
      list: [
        1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 ,
        9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, - ] },
    {
      size: 1,
      list: [32] },
    null,
    {
      size: 32,
      list: [
        1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 ,
        9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32] }
  ]
}
```

So my question is, **how can you build such a tree that only has 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 nodes at each level, which allows for inserting or removing nodes at any place in the overall conceptual "array", where the leaf nodes in the tree don't need to be at any specific level? How to implement the `splice` method?**

For this question, don't worry about compactification just yet, I will try and see if I can figure that out on my own first. For this question, just leave junk and nulls around wherever they end up being, which is less than ideal. I mean, if you know how to compactify things easily, then by all means include it, but I think it will add significantly to the answer, so the default should be to leave it out of the answer :)

Also note, the arrays should be treated as if they are static arrays, i.e. they can't dynamically grow in size.

The algorithm for `insertItemAt(index)` would work something like this:

- Find the appropriate leaf array to put the item in. (By traversing down based on size information).
- If the leaf has some room in it (as null pointers at the end of the leaf array), then just shift the items to make room for the item at its exact index.
- If the leaf is too short, replace it with a longer one, and place the item in that leaf.
- If the leaf is max length (32), then attempt to add another leaf sibling. Can't just easily do that if there are 32 siblings... Or if there are not already null siblings in place if it's shorter.
- If the leaf is max length and there aren't max length siblings, then check for a free null sibling. If there are no more free siblings, then double the number of siblings with null pointers, and create the next array and put it there.
- **If the leaf is max length and the siblings are max length, and the parent is max length, I have a hard time imagining what the algorithm should do exactly in order to grow while adhering to these constraints, which is why I struggle here.**

The algorithm for `removeItemAt(index)` (the second piece of functionality of `splice`) would do something like this:

- Find the appropriate item based on index and size information of each array node in the tree.
- Set it to null.
- Compactify surrounding null pointers if there are multiple of them at the same level. Bring them down so they equal 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 (probably since we're deleting it will never equal 32). But this portion of the algorithm can be left out, I can probably eventually figure this out, unless you know how to do it quickly.

Here is what I have basically so far.

```js
const createTree = () => createTreeLeaf()

const createTreeContainer = () => {
  return {
    type: 'container',
    list: [],
    size: 0
  }
}

const createTreeLeaf = () => {
  return {
    type: 'leaf',
    list: [],
    size: 0
  }
}

const setItemAt = (tree, item, index) => {
  let nodes = [tree]
  let startSize = 0
  a:
  while (true) {
    b:
    for (let i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; i++) {
      let node = nodes[i]
      let endSize = startSize + node.size

      if (startSize <= index && index < endSize) {
        // it's within here.
        if (node.type == 'container') {
          nodes = node.list
          break b
        } else {
          let relativeIndex = index - startSize
          // grow if less than max
          if (relativeIndex > node.size - 1) {
            if (node.size == 32) {
              // grow somehow
            } else {
              let newArray = new Array(node.size * 2)
              node.list.forEach((x, i) => newArray[i] = x)
              node.list = newArray
            }
          }
          if (node.list[relativeIndex] == null) {
            node.size++
          }
          node.list[relativeIndex] = item
          break a
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const insertItemAt = (tree, item, index) => {
  let nodes = [tree]
  let startSize = 0
  a:
  while (true) {
    b:
    for (let i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; i++) {
      let node = nodes[i]
      let endSize = startSize + node.size

      if (startSize <= index && index < endSize) {
        // it's within here.
        if (node.type == 'container') {
          nodes = node.list
          break b
        } else {
          let relativeIndex = index - startSize
          // grow if less than max
          if (relativeIndex > node.size - 1 || isPowerOfTwo(node.size)) {
            if (node.size == 32) {
              // grow somehow
            } else {
              let newArray = new Array(node.size * 2)
              node.list.forEach((x, i) => newArray[i] = x)
              node.list = newArray
            }
          }
          // todo: shift the items over to make room for this item
          break a
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const removeItemAt = (tree, item, index) => {

}

const appendItemToEndOfTree = (tree, item) => {

}

const getLeafContainingIndex = (tree, index) => {
  if (index > tree.size - 1) {
    return { node: null, index: -1 }
  }

  let nodes = [tree]
  let startSize = 0
  a:
  while (true) {
    b:
    for (let i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; i++) {
      let node = nodes[i]
      let endSize = startSize + node.size
      if (startSize <= index && index < endSize) {
        if (node.type == 'container') {
          nodes = node.list
          break b
        } else {
          let relativeIndex = index - startSize
          return { node, index: relativeIndex }
        }
      } else {
        startSize = endSize
      }
    }
  }
}

const getItemAt = (tree, getIndex) => {
  const { node, index } = getLeafContainingIndex(tree, getIndex)
  if (!node) return null
  return node.list[index]
}

const isPowerOfTwo = (x) => {
  return (x != 0) && ((x & (x - 1)) == 0)
}

const log = tree => console.log(JSON.stringify(tree.list))

// demo
const tree = createTree()

setItemAt(tree, { pos: '1st', attempt: 1 }, 0)
log(tree)
setItemAt(tree, { pos: '2nd', attempt: 2 }, 1)
log(tree)
setItemAt(tree, { pos: '2nd', attempt: 3 }, 1)
log(tree)
setItemAt(tree, { pos: '3rd', attempt: 4 }, 2)
log(tree)
```

The "grow somehow" section would work sort of like this I think...

- Keep index of array relative to parent.
- If the leaf length is 32, then you need to create more room in the parent.
- If parent array is length 32, divide the parent array in half, so there are two 16 item arrays. Then wrap the parent nodes in a new array (now we have a 2-node array and 2 16-node arrays, which both fit the constraints).
- Change the indexes on the second array.
- Get index of insertion relative to parent.
- Find which of the two nodes to select based on the relative index for the insertion node.
- Repeat the process (recurse into the parent node and try again to insert, since it has a new structure now).

*NOTE: This should work like a compact list. This means it never has any blank spaces inside of it (except the trailing nulls, which aren't spaces in the array, only placeholders to support future inserts according to the 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 constraints). This means you can only (1) squeeze an item in between two existing, (2) append after an item, (3) prepend before an item, and (4) delete an item (only having the empty space filled by shifting the leaf items to the left).*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226957/discussion-on-question-by-lance-pollard-how-to-build-a-tree-array-into-which-o).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requirements are close to what a [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) offers. A 32-ary B+ tree would provide these properties:

- The leaves of the tree are all at the same level
- The actual data is stored only in the leaves
- All internal nodes, except the root, have at least 16 children (not counting the `null` fillers)
- All leaves, except the root, have at least 16 values (not counting the `null` fillers)
- If the root is not a leaf, then it will have at least 2 children

In addition it has this useful feature:

- Leaf nodes are commonly maintained in a linked list, so that iteration of that list will visit the data in its intended order

B+ trees are *search* trees, which is a feature that does not match your requirements. So that means the typical *keys*, that are stored in the internal nodes of a B+ tree, are not needed here.

On the other hand, you require that elements can be identified by index. As you already suggested, you can extend each node with a property that provides the total count of data values that are stored in the leaves of the subtree rooted in that node. This will allow to find a data value by index in logarithmic time.

### Dynamic node sizes

As to the requirement that node sizes should be powers of 2 up to 32: B+ trees do not provide variable node sizes. But note that *all* nodes in this B+ tree are guaranteed to have at least 16 used entries. The only exception is the root, which could have any number of used entries.

So in a first version of my answer I did not focus too much on this requirement: implementing it would mean that *sometimes* you could save some space in an non-root node by limiting its size to 16 instead of 32. But the very next insertion in that node would require it to extend (again) to a size of 32. So I considered it might not be worth the effort. Adapting the record size for the root would also not contribute much gain as it just applies to that single node.

After a comment about this, I adapted the implementation, so each node will reduce or extend its size to the previous/next power of 2 as soon as possible/needed. This means that non-root nodes may sometimes get their size reduced to 16 (while they have 16 items/children), and the root can have any of the possible powers (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32) as size.

### Other implementation choices

In line with your preference I avoided the use of recursion.

I opted to include the following properties in each node:

- `children`: this is the list of either child nodes or (in case of a leaf) of data values. This list is an array with 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 or 32 slots, where the non-used slots are filled with `null`. This is very un-JavaScript like, but I understand you are actually targeting a different language, so I went with it.
- `childCount`: this indicates how many slots in the above array are actually used. We could do without this, if we could assume that `null` can never be used as data, and an occurrence would indicate the end of the real content. But anyway, I went for this property. So in theory, the content could now actually include intended `null` values.
- `treeSize`. this is the total number of data items that are in the leaves of the subtree that is rooted in this node. If this is itself a leaf node, then it will *always* be equal to `childCount`.
- `parent`. B+ trees don't really need a back reference from a child to a parent, but I went with it for this implementation, also because it makes it somewhat easier to provide a non-recursion based implementation (which you seem to prefer).
- `prev`, `next`: these properties reference sibling nodes (in the same level), so that each level of the tree has its nodes in one, doubly linked list. B+ trees commonly have this at the bottom level only, but it is also handy to have at the other levels.

## B+ Tree Algorithm

#### Insertion

You already sketched an algorithm for insertion. It would indeed go like this:

- Locate the leaf where the value should be inserted
- If that leaf has room for it, insert the value there and update the treeSize (you called it size), propagating that increase upward in the tree up to the root.
- Otherwise, check if the node has a neighbor to which it could shift some items, so to make room for the new value. If so, go do it, and stop.
- Otherwise, create a new leaf, and move half of the node's values into it. Then there is room to insert the value. Depending on the index, it will be in the old or new node
- Now the task is to insert the new node as sibling in the parent node. Use the same algorithm to perform that action, but on the level above.

If the root needs to split, then create a new root node that will have the two split nodes as its children.

During the execution of this algorithm, the properties of the impacted nodes should of course be well maintained.

#### Deletion

- Locate the leaf where the value should be deleted.
- Remove the value from that leaf, and update the treeSize property, and also upward in the tree up to the root.
- If the node is the root, or the node has more than 16 used slots, then stop.
- The node has too few values, so look at a neighbor to see whether it could merge with this one, or otherwise share some of its entries for redistribution.
- If the items in the chosen neighbor and this one could not fit in one node, then redistribute those items, so each still has at least 16 of them, and stop. There is a boundary case where the node has 16 items, but the neighbor has 17. In that case there is no advantage in redistributing values. Then also stop.
- Otherwise merge the items from the chosen neighbor into the current node.
- Repeat this algorithm for deleting the now empty neighbor from the level above.

If the root ends up with just one child node, then make the root to be that single child node, removing the top level.

## Implementation

Below you'll find an implementation of a `Tree` class. It includes the methods you were asking for:

- `getItemAt`
- `setItemAt`
- `removeItemAt`
- `insertItemAt`

It also includes some extra methods:

- `Symbol.iterator`: this makes the tree instance iterable. This allows for easy iteration of values, using the linked list of the bottom level of the tree.
- `print`: speaks for itself
- `verify`: this visits every node of the tree in a breadth-first traversal, checking that all conditions are met, and no inconsistencies exist. Among many other tests, it also verifies that each node has a fill factor of more than 50%, or otherwise put: that the array size is the least possible power of two to host the content. If a test fails, a simple exception will be thrown. I didn't put any effort in providing context to the error: they should not ever occur.

### Snippet

Running the snippet below will create one tree instance, and perform 1000 insertions, 1000 update/retrievals, and 1000 deletions. In parallel the same actions are done on a 1-dimensional array, using `splice`. After each step, the values from the tree iteration are compared with the array, and the consistency of the tree is verified. The test is performed with a maximum node capacity of 8 (instead of 32), so the tree grows faster vertically, and a lot more shifting, splitting and merging needs to happen.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(capacity) {
        // Mimic fixed-size array (avoid accidentally growing it)
        this.children = Object.seal(Array(capacity).fill(null));
        this.childCount = 0; // Number of used slots in children array
        this.treeSize = 0; // Total number of values in this subtree
        // Maintain back-link to parent.
        this.parent = null;
        // Per level in the tree, maintain a doubly linked list
        this.prev = this.next = null;
    }
    setCapacity(capacity) {
        if (capacity < 1) return;
        // Here we make a new array, and copy the data into it
        let children = Object.seal(Array(capacity).fill(null));
        for (let i = 0; i < this.childCount; i++) children[i] = this.children[i];
        this.children = children;
    }
    isLeaf() {
        return !(this.children[0] instanceof Node);
    }
    index() {
        return this.parent.children.indexOf(this);
    }
    updateTreeSize(start, end, sign=1) {        
        let sum = 0;
        if (this.isLeaf()) {
            sum = end - start;
        } else {
            for (let i = start; i < end; i++) sum += this.children[i].treeSize;
        }
        if (!sum) return;
        sum *= sign;
        // Apply the sum change to this node and all its ancestors
        for (let node = this; node; node = node.parent) {
            node.treeSize += sum;
        }
    }
    wipe(start, end) {
        this.updateTreeSize(start, end, -1);
        this.children.copyWithin(start, end, this.childCount);
        for (let i = this.childCount - end + start; i < this.childCount; i++) {
            this.children[i] = null;
        }
        this.childCount -= end - start;
        // Reduce allocated size if possible
        if (this.childCount * 2 <= this.children.length) this.setCapacity(this.children.length / 2);
    }
    moveFrom(neighbor, target, start, count=1) {
        // Note: `start` can have two meanings:
        //   if neighbor is null, it is the value/Node to move to the target
        //   if neighbor is a Node, it is the index from where value(s) have to be moved to the target
        // Make room in target node
        if (this.childCount + count > this.children.length) this.setCapacity(this.children.length * 2);
        this.children.copyWithin(target + count, target, Math.max(target + count, this.childCount));
        this.childCount += count;
        if (neighbor !== null) {
            // Copy the children
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                this.children[target + i] = neighbor.children[start + i];
            }
            // Remove the original references
            neighbor.wipe(start, start + count);
        } else {
            this.children[target] = start; // start is value to insert
        }
        this.updateTreeSize(target, target + count, 1);
        // Set parent link(s)
        if (!this.isLeaf()) {
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                this.children[target + i].parent = this;
            }
        }
    }
    moveToNext(count) {
        this.next.moveFrom(this, 0, this.childCount - count, count);
    }
    moveFromNext(count) {
        this.moveFrom(this.next, this.childCount, 0, count);
    }
    basicRemove(index) {
        if (!this.isLeaf()) {
            // Take node out of the level's linked list
            let prev = this.children[index].prev;
            let next = this.children[index].next;
            if (prev) prev.next = next;
            if (next) next.prev = prev;
        }
        this.wipe(index, index + 1);
    }
    basicInsert(index, value) {
        this.moveFrom(null, index, value);
        if (value instanceof Node) {
            // Insert node in the level's linked list
            if (index > 0) {
                value.prev = this.children[index-1];
                value.next = value.prev.next;
            } else if (this.childCount > 1) {
                value.next = this.children[1];
                value.prev = value.next.prev;
            }
            if (value.prev) value.prev.next = value;
            if (value.next) value.next.prev = value;
        }
    }
    pairWithSmallest() {            
        return this.prev && (!this.next || this.next.childCount > this.prev.childCount)
            ? [this.prev, this] : [this, this.next];
    }
    toString() {
        return "[" + this.children.map(v => v??"-").join() + "]";
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor(nodeCapacity=32) {
        this.nodeCapacity = nodeCapacity;
        this.root = new Node(1);
        this.first = this.root; // Head of doubly linked list at bottom level
    }
    locate(offset) {
        let node = this.root;
        // Normalise argument
        offset = offset < 0 ? Math.max(0, node.treeSize + offset) : Math.min(offset, node.treeSize);

        while (!node.isLeaf()) {
            let index = 0;
            let child = node.children[index];
            while (offset > child.treeSize || offset === child.treeSize && child.next) {
                offset -= child.treeSize;
                child = node.children[++index];
            }
            node = child;
        }
        return [node, offset];
    }
    getItemAt(offset) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index < node.childCount) return node.children[index];
    }
    setItemAt(offset, value) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index < node.childCount) node.children[index] = value;
    }
    removeItemAt(offset) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index >= node.childCount) return;

        while (true) {
            console.assert(node.isLeaf() || node.children[index].treeSize === 0);
            node.basicRemove(index);

            // Exit when node's fill ratio is fine
            if (!node.parent || node.childCount * 2 > this.nodeCapacity) return;
            // Node has potentially too few children, we should either merge or redistribute
            
            let [left, right] = node.pairWithSmallest();
            
            if (!left || !right) { // A node with no siblings? Must become the root!
                this.root = node;
                node.parent = null;
                return;
            }
            let sumCount = left.childCount + right.childCount;
            let childCount = sumCount >> 1;
            
            // Check whether to merge or to redistribute
            if (sumCount > this.nodeCapacity) { // redistribute
                // Move some data from the bigger to the smaller node
                let shift = childCount - node.childCount;
                if (!shift) { // Boundary case: when a redistribution would bring no improvement
                    console.assert(node.childCount * 2 === this.nodeCapacity && sumCount === this.nodeCapacity + 1);
                    return;
                }
                if (node === left) { // move some children from right to left
                    left.moveFromNext(shift);
                } else { // move some children from left to right
                    left.moveToNext(shift);
                }
                return;
            }
            
            // Merge:
            // Move all data from the right to the left
            left.moveFromNext(right.childCount);
            // Prepare to delete right node
            node = right.parent;
            index = right.index();
        }
    }
    insertItemAt(offset, value) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        while (node.childCount === this.nodeCapacity) { // No room here
            if (index === 0 && node.prev && node.prev.childCount < this.nodeCapacity) {
                return node.prev.basicInsert(node.prev.childCount, value);
            }
            // Check whether we can redistribute (to avoid a split)
            if (node !== this.root) {
                let [left, right] = node.pairWithSmallest();
                let joinedIndex = left === node ? index : left.childCount + index;
                let sumCount = left.childCount + right.childCount + 1;
                if (sumCount <= 2 * this.nodeCapacity) { // redistribute
                    let childCount = sumCount >> 1;
                    if (node === right) { // redistribute to the left
                        let insertInLeft = joinedIndex < childCount;
                        left.moveFromNext(childCount - left.childCount - +insertInLeft);
                    } else { // redistribute to the right
                        let insertInRight = index >= sumCount - childCount;
                        left.moveToNext(childCount - right.childCount - +insertInRight);
                    }
                    if (joinedIndex > left.childCount || 
                            joinedIndex === left.childCount && left.childCount > right.childCount) {
                        right.basicInsert(joinedIndex - left.childCount, value);
                    } else {
                        left.basicInsert(joinedIndex, value);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            // Cannot redistribute: split node
            let childCount = node.childCount >> 1;
            // Create a new node that will later become the right sibling of this node
            let sibling = new Node(childCount);
            // Move half of node node's data to it
            sibling.moveFrom(node, 0, childCount, childCount);
            // Insert the value in either the current node or the new one
            if (index > node.childCount) {
                sibling.basicInsert(index - node.childCount, value);
            } else {
                node.basicInsert(index, value);
            }
            // Is this the root? 
            if (!node.parent) {
                // ...then first create a parent, which is the new root
                this.root = new Node(2);
                this.root.basicInsert(0, node);
            }
            // Prepare for inserting the sibling node into the tree
            index = node.index() + 1;
            node = node.parent;
            value = sibling;
        }
        node.basicInsert(index, value);
    }
    /* Below this point: these methods are optional */
    * [Symbol.iterator]() { // Make tree iterable
        let i = 0;
        for (let node = this.first; node; node = node.next) {
            for (let i = 0; i < node.childCount; i++) yield node.children[i];
        }
    }
    print() {
        console.log(this.root && this.root.toString());
    }
    verify() {
        // Raise an error when the tree violates one of the required properties
        if (!this.root) return; // An empty tree is fine.
        if (this.root.parent) throw "root should not have a parent";
        // Perform a breadth first traversal
        let q = [this.root];
        while (q.length) {
            if (q[0].isLeaf() && this.first !== q[0]) throw "this.first is not pointing to first leaf";
            let level = [];
            let last = null;
            for (let parent of q) {
                if (!(parent instanceof Node)) throw "parent is not instance of Node";
                if (parent.children.length > this.nodeCapacity) throw "node's children array is too large";
                if (parent.childCount > 0 && parent.childCount * 2 <= parent.children.length) throw "node's fill ratio is too low";
                for (let i = parent.childCount; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
                    if (parent.children[i] !== null) throw "child beyond childCount should be null but is not";
                }
                let treeSize = parent.treeSize;
                if (parent.isLeaf()) {
                    for (let value of parent.children.slice(0, parent.childCount)) {
                        if (value === null) throw "leaf has a null as value";
                        if (value instanceof Node) throw "leaf has a Node as value";
                    }
                    if (parent.treeSize !== parent.childCount) throw "leaf has mismatch in treeSize and childCount";
                } else {
                    for (let node of parent.children.slice(0, parent.childCount)) {
                        if (node === null) throw "internal node has a null as value";
                        if (!(node instanceof Node)) throw "internal node has a non-Node as value";
                        if (node.parent !== parent) throw "wrong parent";
                        if (node.prev !== last) throw "prev link incorrect";
                        if (last && last.next !== node) throw "next link incorrect";
                        if (last && last.children.length + node.children.length <= this.nodeCapacity) {
                            throw "two consecutive siblings have a total number of children that is too small";
                        }
                        if (node.childCount * 2 < this.nodeCapacity) {
                            throw "internal node is too small: " + node;
                        }
                        level.push(node);
                        last = node;
                        treeSize -= node.treeSize;
                    }
                    if (treeSize) throw "internal node treeSize sum mismatches";
                }
            }
            if (last && last.next) throw "last node in level has a next reference";
            q = level;
        }
    }
    test(count=100, option=3) {
        // option:
        //     0 = always insert & delete at left side (offset 0)
        //     1 = always insert & delete at right side
        //     2 = always insert & delete at middle
        //     3 = insert & delete at random offsets
        // Create array to perform the same operations on it as on the tree
        let arr = [];
        // Perform a series of insertions
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // Choose random insertion index
            let index = Array.isArray(option) ? option[i] : [0, i, i >> 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1))][option];
            // Perform same insertion in array and tree
            arr.splice(index, 0, i);
            this.insertItemAt(index, i);
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of values in the array is the same as in the tree
            if (arr+"" !== [...this]+"") throw i + ": tree not same as array";
        }
        // Perform a series of updates
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // Choose random update index
            let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
            // Perform same insertion in array and tree
            arr[index] += count;
            this.setItemAt(index, this.getItemAt(index) + count);
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of values in the array is the same as in the tree
            if (arr+"" !== [...this]+"") throw "tree not same as array";
        }
        // Perform a series of deletions
        for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // Choose random deletion index
            let index = [0, i, i >> 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1))][option];
            // Perform same deletion in array and tree
            arr.splice(index, 1);
            this.removeItemAt(index);
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of values in the array is the same as in the tree
            if (arr+"" !== [...this]+"") throw "tree not same as array";
        }
    }
}

// Perform 1000 insertions, 1000 updates, and 1000 deletions on a tree with node capacity of 8
new Tree(8).test(1000);
console.log("all tests completed");
```

Comment: You even added a loop invariant if I'm looking at this correctly with `console.assert`? That's awesome :) Just getting to examine it in more detail. And I think `copyWithin` is just a built-in method to shift items over in an array (never seen/used that method before).

Comment: I haven't thought about this deeply yet relative to your answer, but not having nodes start off being 1, then 2, then 4, then 8, then 16, to 32 in size, this means you can't have 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. item arrays that are more compact. I was hoping this would allow you to save space on small arrays like arrays with only 4 items, 6 items, etc. What if I had 10,000 4-item arrays, for example, which wouldn't be uncommon in my situation. For example, using arrays to store record fields, where there might be only 4 fields on a particular record type.

Comment: Yes, I confirm all you say here. I thought it not relevant to save a few bytes here and there, at the cost of more processing overhead to shrink and extend arrays. But if you find this important, then I will modify the code and add the logic for this.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind modifying it that would be really nice, I have your original implementation so you could save that as well and include both perhaps.

Comment: There are still several choices to make: (1) root node should grow from 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 to 32 as needed. (2) when other nodes are created for holding 16 items, they should be created with size 16 instead of 32, and extend to size 32 when an item is inserted in it. (3) When a deletion happens, nodes that are left with only 16 items should shrink from size 32 to 16. (4) When the root gets items deleted from it, it should shrink to 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 as possible. Do you want all four of these features?

Comment: Yes, and when deletion happens down to 8 items, it should shrink to 8 items, etc.

Comment: OK, but in the tree I have implemented deletion will never happen down to 8 items -- the only exception is the root. This is because if the item count gets below 16, a merge or redistribution of items will kick in. That way non-root nodes will always have a number of items between 16 and 32.

Comment: I updated the answer. I could not keep the original version, as I bumped into the answer-size limit. So in this version the method `Node#setCapacity` is added. The `verify` method will also check that each node has the smallest (power of 2) size needed to host the content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227066/discussion-between-lance-pollard-and-trincot).

Comment: When I insert 256 items at index i starting from 0, only the last array has 32 items, every other array has 16 items. When I insert 256 items at index 0, always at index 0, then only the first array has 32 items, every other array has 16. So something is off. When I add 256 items at index 0, then remove 224 items at index 0, I should end up 1 array at 32 items, but instead i end up with 2 arrays having 16 items each. If I remove 225 items, I have 1 array with 31 items, which is correct.

Comment: When inserting at the end (pushing), I would expect each array to fill up to 32 items one after the next I think.

Comment: About that last comment: this would mean that if you insert a few times more at index 0, you would have to perform a shift of values *every* time. That is not efficient. By the B+ tree principle, you would split at the 33th value into two almost equally sized nodes, so that at least the next few insertions will not need the overhead of shifting.

Comment: Yeah I was worried about that, darn.

Comment: For the other comments: I updated the algorithm to avoid a node split at insertion when items can be moved to a neighbor. Also, a deletion will avoid a node size of half-capacity unless the neighbors have just one more item. The latter case is accepted, i.e. you could get a level with [17] [16] [17] [16] ..., but not [16] [16], where the numbers are numbers of items. I also posted some comments in the chat.

Comment: Works beautifully!

Comment: @trincot is it straightforward to convert this to a b+ search tree, where we can look up objects by an arbitrary string key? Should I ask a separate question for that or can you point me in the right direction on what to modify? I'm thinking about a totally different system that also uses a b+tree concept, but is for looking up items by key, whereas this question is for treating b+trees like arrays. But also keeping the power of two constraint.

Comment: Well, yes, that is actually what B+ trees are: search trees. You would need to put back in the concept of the original B+ tree: the keys in the internal nodes: each internal node would need an extra array of n-1 keys (where n is the number of children it has). These keys delimit the range of values in the subtrees. They are copies of leftmost leaf-values. Of course, a change in the tree will also affect these keys, so you need to add logic for that. This deserves a new question.

Comment: @trincot how does this actually differ from a [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) data structure? It seems to be the same thing, assuming you were storing chunks of a single string in each index.

Comment: It is quite similar, but a rope is a *binary* tree, so you'll be creating and deleting nodes a whole lot more (there's no packing to 4, 8, 16, or 32), and it is by default *not balanced*, so you would need to add logic for that to avoid worst case time complexities of *O(n)*.

Comment: Hi again! I just asked a question about [how to add a `Tree.allocate` function to the B+tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71886183/how-to-implement-an-allocate-function-for-this-index-based-btree-in-javascrip). But I noticed (in the examples I posted), `push`-ing to the tree doesn't result in what you'd conceptually expect (fill up the first arrays first). Instead, the second to last is partially filled, and the last is shifted over one every time you push, so the whole array has to update. Is there a way to fix this you can see?