# How to convert array-like B+tree to hash-like B+ search tree?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have just recently learned about B+trees, after asking [How to build a tree array into which / out of which items can be spliced, which only allows arrays of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545292/how-to-build-a-tree-array-into-which-out-of-which-items-can-be-spliced-which/65612476#65612476), and seeing a [wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65612476/169992) implementing the B+tree according to the constraints. To summarize, basically that question was looking for a tree-like structure that we could treat as an array (find by index, remove at index, insert at index, etc.). In addition, the arrays that implement the tree nodes can only contain powers of 2 number of elements, up to 32 items (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32). Additionally, they should be relatively compacted as the answer showed, essentially making sure that every node was filled to the brim with 32 items before creating new sub arrays (i.e. so you don't end up with a bunch of 16-item arrays).

The answer is kind of complex and I am still picking it apart. But as I master the inner details of it, I would like to see how a "real B+ search tree" would look in comparison. That is, a B+tree that actually has *keys* and that you treat sort of like a hash table (find by *key*, remove by key, insert with key, etc.). Whereas the other one was by *index*, this would be by key. Ideally arbitrary keys (perhaps with a `getKey` function), or just string or integer keys.

So I'm wondering what needs to be modified in that original answer, copied here:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(capacity) {
        // Mimic fixed-size array (avoid accidentally growing it)
        this.children = Object.seal(Array(capacity).fill(null));
        this.childCount = 0; // Number of used slots in children array
        this.treeSize = 0; // Total number of values in this subtree
        // Maintain back-link to parent.
        this.parent = null;
        // Per level in the tree, maintain a doubly linked list
        this.prev = this.next = null;
    }
    setCapacity(capacity) {
        if (capacity < 1) return;
        // Here we make a new array, and copy the data into it
        let children = Object.seal(Array(capacity).fill(null));
        for (let i = 0; i < this.childCount; i++) children[i] = this.children[i];
        this.children = children;
    }
    isLeaf() {
        return !(this.children[0] instanceof Node);
    }
    index() {
        return this.parent.children.indexOf(this);
    }
    updateTreeSize(start, end, sign=1) {        
        let sum = 0;
        if (this.isLeaf()) {
            sum = end - start;
        } else {
            for (let i = start; i < end; i++) sum += this.children[i].treeSize;
        }
        if (!sum) return;
        sum *= sign;
        // Apply the sum change to this node and all its ancestors
        for (let node = this; node; node = node.parent) {
            node.treeSize += sum;
        }
    }
    wipe(start, end) {
        this.updateTreeSize(start, end, -1);
        this.children.copyWithin(start, end, this.childCount);
        for (let i = this.childCount - end + start; i < this.childCount; i++) {
            this.children[i] = null;
        }
        this.childCount -= end - start;
        // Reduce allocated size if possible
        if (this.childCount * 2 <= this.children.length) this.setCapacity(this.children.length / 2);
    }
    moveFrom(neighbor, target, start, count=1) {
        // Note: `start` can have two meanings:
        //   if neighbor is null, it is the value/Node to move to the target
        //   if neighbor is a Node, it is the index from where value(s) have to be moved to the target
        // Make room in target node
        if (this.childCount + count > this.children.length) this.setCapacity(this.children.length * 2);
        this.children.copyWithin(target + count, target, Math.max(target + count, this.childCount));
        this.childCount += count;
        if (neighbor !== null) {
            // Copy the children
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                this.children[target + i] = neighbor.children[start + i];
            }
            // Remove the original references
            neighbor.wipe(start, start + count);
        } else {
            this.children[target] = start; // start is value to insert
        }
        this.updateTreeSize(target, target + count, 1);
        // Set parent link(s)
        if (!this.isLeaf()) {
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                this.children[target + i].parent = this;
            }
        }
    }
    moveToNext(count) {
        this.next.moveFrom(this, 0, this.childCount - count, count);
    }
    moveFromNext(count) {
        this.moveFrom(this.next, this.childCount, 0, count);
    }
    basicRemove(index) {
        if (!this.isLeaf()) {
            // Take node out of the level's linked list
            let prev = this.children[index].prev;
            let next = this.children[index].next;
            if (prev) prev.next = next;
            if (next) next.prev = prev;
        }
        this.wipe(index, index + 1);
    }
    basicInsert(index, value) {
        this.moveFrom(null, index, value);
        if (value instanceof Node) {
            // Insert node in the level's linked list
            if (index > 0) {
                value.prev = this.children[index-1];
                value.next = value.prev.next;
            } else if (this.childCount > 1) {
                value.next = this.children[1];
                value.prev = value.next.prev;
            }
            if (value.prev) value.prev.next = value;
            if (value.next) value.next.prev = value;
        }
    }
    pairWithSmallest() {            
        return this.prev && (!this.next || this.next.childCount > this.prev.childCount)
            ? [this.prev, this] : [this, this.next];
    }
    toString() {
        return "[" + this.children.map(v => v??"-").join() + "]";
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor(nodeCapacity=32) {
        this.nodeCapacity = nodeCapacity;
        this.root = new Node(1);
        this.first = this.root; // Head of doubly linked list at bottom level
    }
    locate(offset) {
        let node = this.root;
        // Normalise argument
        offset = offset < 0 ? Math.max(0, node.treeSize + offset) : Math.min(offset, node.treeSize);

        while (!node.isLeaf()) {
            let index = 0;
            let child = node.children[index];
            while (offset > child.treeSize || offset === child.treeSize && child.next) {
                offset -= child.treeSize;
                child = node.children[++index];
            }
            node = child;
        }
        return [node, offset];
    }
    getItemAt(offset) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index < node.childCount) return node.children[index];
    }
    setItemAt(offset, value) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index < node.childCount) node.children[index] = value;
    }
    removeItemAt(offset) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index >= node.childCount) return;

        while (true) {
            console.assert(node.isLeaf() || node.children[index].treeSize === 0);
            node.basicRemove(index);

            // Exit when node's fill ratio is fine
            if (!node.parent || node.childCount * 2 > this.nodeCapacity) return;
            // Node has potentially too few children, we should either merge or redistribute
            
            let [left, right] = node.pairWithSmallest();
            
            if (!left || !right) { // A node with no siblings? Must become the root!
                this.root = node;
                node.parent = null;
                return;
            }
            let sumCount = left.childCount + right.childCount;
            let childCount = sumCount >> 1;
            
            // Check whether to merge or to redistribute
            if (sumCount > this.nodeCapacity) { // redistribute
                // Move some data from the bigger to the smaller node
                let shift = childCount - node.childCount;
                if (!shift) { // Boundary case: when a redistribution would bring no improvement
                    console.assert(node.childCount * 2 === this.nodeCapacity && sumCount === this.nodeCapacity + 1);
                    return;
                }
                if (node === left) { // move some children from right to left
                    left.moveFromNext(shift);
                } else { // move some children from left to right
                    left.moveToNext(shift);
                }
                return;
            }
            
            // Merge:
            // Move all data from the right to the left
            left.moveFromNext(right.childCount);
            // Prepare to delete right node
            node = right.parent;
            index = right.index();
        }
    }
    insertItemAt(offset, value) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        while (node.childCount === this.nodeCapacity) { // No room here
            if (index === 0 && node.prev && node.prev.childCount < this.nodeCapacity) {
                return node.prev.basicInsert(node.prev.childCount, value);
            }
            // Check whether we can redistribute (to avoid a split)
            if (node !== this.root) {
                let [left, right] = node.pairWithSmallest();
                let joinedIndex = left === node ? index : left.childCount + index;
                let sumCount = left.childCount + right.childCount + 1;
                if (sumCount <= 2 * this.nodeCapacity) { // redistribute
                    let childCount = sumCount >> 1;
                    if (node === right) { // redistribute to the left
                        let insertInLeft = joinedIndex < childCount;
                        left.moveFromNext(childCount - left.childCount - +insertInLeft);
                    } else { // redistribute to the right
                        let insertInRight = index >= sumCount - childCount;
                        left.moveToNext(childCount - right.childCount - +insertInRight);
                    }
                    if (joinedIndex > left.childCount || 
                            joinedIndex === left.childCount && left.childCount > right.childCount) {
                        right.basicInsert(joinedIndex - left.childCount, value);
                    } else {
                        left.basicInsert(joinedIndex, value);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            // Cannot redistribute: split node
            let childCount = node.childCount >> 1;
            // Create a new node that will later become the right sibling of this node
            let sibling = new Node(childCount);
            // Move half of node node's data to it
            sibling.moveFrom(node, 0, childCount, childCount);
            // Insert the value in either the current node or the new one
            if (index > node.childCount) {
                sibling.basicInsert(index - node.childCount, value);
            } else {
                node.basicInsert(index, value);
            }
            // Is this the root? 
            if (!node.parent) {
                // ...then first create a parent, which is the new root
                this.root = new Node(2);
                this.root.basicInsert(0, node);
            }
            // Prepare for inserting the sibling node into the tree
            index = node.index() + 1;
            node = node.parent;
            value = sibling;
        }
        node.basicInsert(index, value);
    }
    /* Below this point: these methods are optional */
    * [Symbol.iterator]() { // Make tree iterable
        let i = 0;
        for (let node = this.first; node; node = node.next) {
            for (let i = 0; i < node.childCount; i++) yield node.children[i];
        }
    }
    print() {
        console.log(this.root && this.root.toString());
    }
    verify() {
        // Raise an error when the tree violates one of the required properties
        if (!this.root) return; // An empty tree is fine.
        if (this.root.parent) throw "root should not have a parent";
        // Perform a breadth first traversal
        let q = [this.root];
        while (q.length) {
            if (q[0].isLeaf() && this.first !== q[0]) throw "this.first is not pointing to first leaf";
            let level = [];
            let last = null;
            for (let parent of q) {
                if (!(parent instanceof Node)) throw "parent is not instance of Node";
                if (parent.children.length > this.nodeCapacity) throw "node's children array is too large";
                if (parent.childCount > 0 && parent.childCount * 2 <= parent.children.length) throw "node's fill ratio is too low";
                for (let i = parent.childCount; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
                    if (parent.children[i] !== null) throw "child beyond childCount should be null but is not";
                }
                let treeSize = parent.treeSize;
                if (parent.isLeaf()) {
                    for (let value of parent.children.slice(0, parent.childCount)) {
                        if (value === null) throw "leaf has a null as value";
                        if (value instanceof Node) throw "leaf has a Node as value";
                    }
                    if (parent.treeSize !== parent.childCount) throw "leaf has mismatch in treeSize and childCount";
                } else {
                    for (let node of parent.children.slice(0, parent.childCount)) {
                        if (node === null) throw "internal node has a null as value";
                        if (!(node instanceof Node)) throw "internal node has a non-Node as value";
                        if (node.parent !== parent) throw "wrong parent";
                        if (node.prev !== last) throw "prev link incorrect";
                        if (last && last.next !== node) throw "next link incorrect";
                        if (last && last.children.length + node.children.length <= this.nodeCapacity) {
                            throw "two consecutive siblings have a total number of children that is too small";
                        }
                        if (node.childCount * 2 < this.nodeCapacity) {
                            throw "internal node is too small: " + node;
                        }
                        level.push(node);
                        last = node;
                        treeSize -= node.treeSize;
                    }
                    if (treeSize) throw "internal node treeSize sum mismatches";
                }
            }
            if (last && last.next) throw "last node in level has a next reference";
            q = level;
        }
    }
    test(count=100, option=3) {
        // option:
        //     0 = always insert & delete at left side (offset 0)
        //     1 = always insert & delete at right side
        //     2 = always insert & delete at middle
        //     3 = insert & delete at random offsets
        // Create array to perform the same operations on it as on the tree
        let arr = [];
        // Perform a series of insertions
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // Choose random insertion index
            let index = Array.isArray(option) ? option[i] : [0, i, i >> 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1))][option];
            // Perform same insertion in array and tree
            arr.splice(index, 0, i);
            this.insertItemAt(index, i);
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of values in the array is the same as in the tree
            if (arr+"" !== [...this]+"") throw i + ": tree not same as array";
        }
        // Perform a series of updates
        for (let i = 0; false && i < count; i++) {
            // Choose random update index
            let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
            // Perform same insertion in array and tree
            arr[index] += count;
            this.setItemAt(index, this.getItemAt(index) + count);
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of values in the array is the same as in the tree
            if (arr+"" !== [...this]+"") throw "tree not same as array";
        }
        // Perform a series of deletions
        for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // Choose random deletion index
            let index = [0, i, i >> 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1))][option];
            // Perform same deletion in array and tree
            arr.splice(index, 1);
            this.removeItemAt(index);
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of values in the array is the same as in the tree
            if (arr+"" !== [...this]+"") throw "tree not same as array";
        }
    }
}

// Perform 1000 insertions, 1000 updates, and 1000 deletions on a tree with node capacity of 8
new Tree(32).test(1000);
console.log("all tests completed");
```

I have started essentially trying to refactor this code into standalone functions rather than object-oriented methods, so I can get it closer to what assembly might require. But I ask in JavaScript because it is most familiar to me and easy to comprehend. In doing so, I have started to look around with where I need to change the support for *indexes* into support for *keys*, but am not entirely sure how much of a change this will be.

I would like to see what the implementation looks like so I can better learn what an actual realistic B+ search tree with these sorts of constraints looks like. I have seen every implementation of B+trees in JavaScript on GitHub, but they are all missing the complicated `remove` method, vary wildly in how they implement things, and don't have the additional constraints needed for the project I'm working on, so it's hard to tell what exactly the keys should be doing in comparison to the integer indices. [Here](https://goneill.co.nz/btree.php) is one B+tree implementation I have been studying, the only one I found with the `remove` method that is also in JavaScript.

Short of that, I am wondering what exactly needs to be *changed* in this implementation above to add support for keys. And how exactly the keys should work at the internal and leaf levels (i.e. do you store the start and end key for the leafs at each parent node? Or how do the keys work exactly so it's efficient?).

On one hand it seems that just a few places of code need to be changed (like the `locate` method), but on the other hand it seems that just adding support for keys will require completely rewriting the whole thing. I am not sure, looking for clarity on that.

```
const locateNode = (tree, key) => {
  let node = tree.root

  while (!checkIfLeaf(node)) {
    let index = 0
    let child = node.children[index]
    while (key != child.key) {
      child = node.children[++index]
    }
    node = child
  }
  
  return node
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: you don't need any more to locate values by their index, right? (Much like in a native Set you can't). Or will you need *also* to have that feature still available? It is possible to have both, but the code will blow up even more ;-)

Comment: No I don't need to lookup by index for this one, just by key :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the `locate` method is the one that changes the most. Your implementation makes linear searches, which is fine, except that the `while` condition should make a `<` comparison instead of `!=`. Just for you to compare, I have included below an implementation that performs a binary search instead of a linear search.

### What to change

- As you want key/value pairs, I would start by creating a class for such a pair:

  ```
  class KeyValue {
      constructor(key, value) {
          this.key = key; 
          this.value = value;
      }
  }
  ```
- Then insert those instead of plain values at the bottom layer of the tree. The method where you set a key/value pair in the tree, would first determine whether to update to an existing key needs to happen, or a new pair needs to be inserted. We could name this method `set` instead of `insert`, and it would take both key and value. It would start as follows:

  ```
  set(key, value) {
      let [node, index] = this.locate(key);
      if (index < node.childCount && node.children[index].key === key) {
          // already present: update the value
          node.children[index].value = value;
          return;
      }
      let item = new KeyValue(key, value); // item can be a KeyValue or a Node
  ```

  ...and then it would continue much like you already have it, but inserting `item`.
- You'll also need a method to update the `key` property upward in the tree, so that it always represents the least key in the subtree below it. A deletion or insertion could of course change what that least key is, and so this method would need to be called in such an event:

  ```
  updateKey() {
      for (let node = this; node; node = node.parent) {
          node.key = node.children[0].key;
      }
  }
  ```

  Note that in the first iteration, `node.children[0]` will reference a `KeyValue` object, while in the other iterations it will reference a `Node` instance.

  We could break out of this loop as soon as a child is not the first child of its parent, but since the `index()` method (to determine that) makes a scan, this might in fact not improve the overall efficiency here. Something to consider in your implementation...
- In both `wipe` and `moveFrom` methods, you'll need to call that new `updateKey` method, as *last* instruction of the function. You can optionally prefix that call with a condition:

  ```
    if (start === 0 && this.childCount > 0) this.updateKey();
  ```
- Replace the `locate` method. As mentioned above, I went for a binary search. But I don't think in JavaScript you'll gain efficiency with a binary search versus a linear search, as the arrays are limited to 32 values, but in a low level language, this could be worth the code:

  ```
  locate(key) {
      let node = this.root;
      let low;
      while (true) {
          // Binary search among keys
          low = 1;
          let high = node.childCount;
          while (low < high) {
              let index = (low + high) >> 1;
              if (key >= node.children[index].key) {
                  low = index + 1;
              } else {
                  high = index;
              }
          }
          low--;
          if (node.isLeaf()) break;
          node = node.children[low];
      }
      if (low < node.childCount && key > node.children[low].key) return [node, low+1];
      return [node, low];
  }
  ```
- Define a `get` method, which will retrieve the value for a given key, just like the JavaScript native `Map#get` method:

  ```
  get(key) {
      let [node, index] = this.locate(key);
      if (index < node.childCount) {
          let keyValue = node.children[index];
          if (keyValue.key === key) return keyValue.value;
      }
  }
  ```
- The `removeItemAt` method would become `remove`, and would start out as follows:

  ```
  remove(key) {
      let [node, index] = this.locate(key);
      if (index >= node.childCount || node.children[index].key !== key) return; // not found
  ```

  ...and then it would continue much like you already had it.
- The iterator would have to return key/value pairs. In line with how JavaScript does this with `Map#entries`, this would yield them as pairs (2-length-arrays).

That's about it. The original code also included methods to verify the consistency of the tree and to test the methods. These would also need to change accordingly, of course.

### Implementation

```js
class KeyValue {
    constructor(key, value) {
        this.key = key; 
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class Node {
    constructor(capacity) {
        // Mimic fixed-size array (avoid accidentally growing it)
        this.children = Object.seal(Array(capacity).fill(null));
        this.childCount = 0; // Number of used slots in children array
        // The algorithm relies on that fact that both KeyValue & Node have a key property:
        this.key = null; // Here it is a property for supporting a search
        // Maintain back-link to parent.
        this.parent = null;
        // Per level in the tree, maintain a doubly linked list
        this.prev = this.next = null;
    }
    setCapacity(capacity) {
        if (capacity < 1) return;
        // Here we make a new array, and copy the data into it
        let children = Object.seal(Array(capacity).fill(null));
        for (let i = 0; i < this.childCount; i++) children[i] = this.children[i];
        this.children = children;
    }
    isLeaf() {
        return !(this.children[0] instanceof Node);
    }
    index() {
        return this.parent.children.indexOf(this);
    }
    updateKey() {
        for (let node = this; node; node = node.parent) {
            node.key = node.children[0].key;
        }
    }
    wipe(start, end) {
        this.children.copyWithin(start, end, this.childCount);
        for (let i = this.childCount - end + start; i < this.childCount; i++) {
            this.children[i] = null;
        }
        this.childCount -= end - start;
        // Reduce allocated size if possible
        if (this.childCount * 2 <= this.children.length) this.setCapacity(this.children.length / 2);
        // Update key if first item changed
        if (start === 0 && this.childCount > 0) this.updateKey();
    }
    moveFrom(neighbor, target, start, count=1) {
        // Note: `start` can have two meanings:
        //   if neighbor is null, it is the value/Node to move to the target
        //   if neighbor is a Node, it is the index from where value(s) have to be moved to the target
        // Make room in target node
        if (this.childCount + count > this.children.length) this.setCapacity(this.children.length * 2);
        this.children.copyWithin(target + count, target, Math.max(target + count, this.childCount));
        this.childCount += count;
        if (neighbor !== null) {
            // Copy the children
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                this.children[target + i] = neighbor.children[start + i];
            }
            // Remove the original references
            neighbor.wipe(start, start + count);
        } else {
            this.children[target] = start; // start is value to insert
        }
        // Set parent link(s)
        if (!this.isLeaf()) {
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                this.children[target + i].parent = this;
            }
        }
        // Update key if first item changed
        if (target === 0) this.updateKey();
    }
    moveToNext(count) {
        this.next.moveFrom(this, 0, this.childCount - count, count);
    }
    moveFromNext(count) {
        this.moveFrom(this.next, this.childCount, 0, count);
    }
    basicRemove(index) {
        if (!this.isLeaf()) {
            // Take node out of the level's linked list
            let prev = this.children[index].prev;
            let next = this.children[index].next;
            if (prev) prev.next = next;
            if (next) next.prev = prev;
        }
        this.wipe(index, index + 1);
    }
    basicInsert(index, value) {
        this.moveFrom(null, index, value);
        if (value instanceof Node) {
            // Insert node in the level's linked list
            if (index > 0) {
                value.prev = this.children[index-1];
                value.next = value.prev.next;
            } else if (this.childCount > 1) {
                value.next = this.children[1];
                value.prev = value.next.prev;
            }
            if (value.prev) value.prev.next = value;
            if (value.next) value.next.prev = value;
        }
    }
    pairWithSmallest() {            
        return this.prev && (!this.next || this.next.childCount > this.prev.childCount)
            ? [this.prev, this] : [this, this.next];
    }
    toString() {
        return "[" + this.children.map(v => v??"-").join() + "]";
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor(nodeCapacity=32) {
        this.nodeCapacity = nodeCapacity;
        this.root = new Node(1);
        this.first = this.root; // Head of doubly linked list at bottom level
    }
    locate(key) {
        let node = this.root;
        let low;
        while (true) {
            // Binary search among keys
            low = 1;
            let high = node.childCount;
            while (low < high) {
                let index = (low + high) >> 1;
                if (key >= node.children[index].key) {
                    low = index + 1;
                } else {
                    high = index;
                }
            }
            low--;
            if (node.isLeaf()) break;
            node = node.children[low];
        }
        if (low < node.childCount && key > node.children[low].key) return [node, low+1];
        return [node, low];
    }
    get(key) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(key);
        if (index < node.childCount) {
            let keyValue = node.children[index];
            if (keyValue.key === key) return keyValue.value;
        }
    }
    set(key, value) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(key);
        if (index < node.childCount && node.children[index].key === key) {
            // already present: update the value
            node.children[index].value = value;
            return;
        }
        let item = new KeyValue(key, value); // item can be a KeyValue or a Node
        while (node.childCount === this.nodeCapacity) { // No room here
            if (index === 0 && node.prev && node.prev.childCount < this.nodeCapacity) {
                return node.prev.basicInsert(node.prev.childCount, item);
            }
            // Check whether we can redistribute (to avoid a split)
            if (node !== this.root) {
                let [left, right] = node.pairWithSmallest();
                let joinedIndex = left === node ? index : left.childCount + index;
                let sumCount = left.childCount + right.childCount + 1;
                if (sumCount <= 2 * this.nodeCapacity) { // redistribute
                    let childCount = sumCount >> 1;
                    if (node === right) { // redistribute to the left
                        let insertInLeft = joinedIndex < childCount;
                        left.moveFromNext(childCount - left.childCount - +insertInLeft);
                    } else { // redistribute to the right
                        let insertInRight = index >= sumCount - childCount;
                        left.moveToNext(childCount - right.childCount - +insertInRight);
                    }
                    if (joinedIndex > left.childCount || 
                            joinedIndex === left.childCount && left.childCount > right.childCount) {
                        right.basicInsert(joinedIndex - left.childCount, item);
                    } else {
                        left.basicInsert(joinedIndex, item);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            // Cannot redistribute: split node
            let childCount = node.childCount >> 1;
            // Create a new node that will later become the right sibling of this node
            let sibling = new Node(childCount);
            // Move half of node node's data to it
            sibling.moveFrom(node, 0, childCount, childCount);
            // Insert the item in either the current node or the new one
            if (index > node.childCount) {
                sibling.basicInsert(index - node.childCount, item);
            } else {
                node.basicInsert(index, item);
            }
            // Is this the root? 
            if (!node.parent) {
                // ...then first create a parent, which is the new root
                this.root = new Node(2);
                this.root.basicInsert(0, node);
            }
            // Prepare for inserting the sibling node into the tree
            index = node.index() + 1;
            node = node.parent;
            item = sibling;  // item is now a Node
        }
        node.basicInsert(index, item);
    }
    remove(key) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(key);
        if (index >= node.childCount || node.children[index].key !== key) return; // not found
        while (true) {
            node.basicRemove(index);

            // Exit when node's fill ratio is fine
            if (!node.parent || node.childCount * 2 > this.nodeCapacity) return;
            // Node has potentially too few children, we should either merge or redistribute
            
            let [left, right] = node.pairWithSmallest();
            
            if (!left || !right) { // A node with no siblings? Must become the root!
                this.root = node;
                node.parent = null;
                return;
            }
            let sumCount = left.childCount + right.childCount;
            let childCount = sumCount >> 1;
            
            // Check whether to merge or to redistribute
            if (sumCount > this.nodeCapacity) { // redistribute
                // Move some data from the bigger to the smaller node
                let shift = childCount - node.childCount;
                if (!shift) { // Boundary case: when a redistribution would bring no improvement
                    console.assert(node.childCount * 2 === this.nodeCapacity && sumCount === this.nodeCapacity + 1);
                    return;
                }
                if (node === left) { // move some children from right to left
                    left.moveFromNext(shift);
                } else { // move some children from left to right
                    left.moveToNext(shift);
                }
                return;
            }
            
            // Merge:
            // Move all data from the right to the left
            left.moveFromNext(right.childCount);
            // Prepare to delete right node
            node = right.parent;
            index = right.index();
        }
    }
    /* Below this point: these methods are optional */
    * [Symbol.iterator]() { // Make tree iterable, yielding key/value pairs
        for (let node = this.first; node; node = node.next) {
            for (let i = 0; i < node.childCount; i++) yield [node.children[i].key, node.children[i].value];
        }
    }
    print() {
        console.log(this.root && this.root.toString());
    }
    verify() {
        // Raise an error when the tree violates one of the required properties
        if (!this.root || !this.root.childCount) return; // An empty tree is fine.
        if (this.root.parent) throw "root should not have a parent";
        // Perform a breadth first traversal
        let q = [this.root];
        while (q.length) {
            if (q[0].isLeaf() && this.first !== q[0]) throw "this.first is not pointing to first leaf";
            let level = [];
            let last = null;
            for (let parent of q) {
                if (!(parent instanceof Node)) throw "parent is not instance of Node";
                if (parent.children.length > this.nodeCapacity) throw "node's children array is too large";
                if (parent.childCount > 0 && parent.childCount * 2 <= parent.children.length) throw "node's fill ratio is too low";
                for (let i = parent.childCount; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
                    if (parent.children[i] !== null) throw "child beyond childCount should be null but is not";
                }
                if (parent.isLeaf()) {
                    if (parent.children[0].key !== parent.key) throw "key does not match with first child value";
                    for (let value of parent.children.slice(0, parent.childCount)) {
                        if (value === null) throw "leaf has a null as value";
                        if (!(value instanceof KeyValue)) throw "leaf has a non-KeyValue item";
                    }
                } else {
                    if (parent.children[0].key !== parent.key) throw "key does not match with first child's key";
                    for (let node of parent.children.slice(0, parent.childCount)) {
                        if (node === null) throw "internal node has a null as value";
                        if (!(node instanceof Node)) throw "internal node has a non-Node as value";
                        if (node.parent !== parent) throw "wrong parent";
                        if (node.prev !== last) throw "prev link incorrect";
                        if (last && last.next !== node) throw "next link incorrect";
                        if (last && last.children.length + node.children.length <= this.nodeCapacity) {
                            throw "two consecutive siblings have a total number of children that is too small";
                        }
                        if (node.childCount * 2 < this.nodeCapacity) {
                            throw "internal node is too small: " + node;
                        }
                        level.push(node);
                        last = node;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (last && last.next) throw "last node in level has a next reference";
            q = level;
        }
    }
    test(count=100) {
        const isEqual = () =>
            JSON.stringify([...map].sort((a,b) => a[0]-b[0])) === JSON.stringify([...this]);
        // Create Map to perform the same operations on it as on the tree
        let map = new Map;
        let max = count*2;
        // Perform a series of insertions
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // Choose random key
            let key = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            let value = key*2;
            // Perform same insertion in array and tree
            map.set(key, value);
            this.set(key, value);
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of key/values in the array is the same as in the tree
            console.assert(isEqual(), "tree not same as array");
        }
        // Perform a series of retrievals and updates
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // Choose random key
            let key = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            // Perform same retrieval in array and tree
            let value = map.get(key);
            if (value !== this.get(key)) throw "get() returns inconsistent result";
            if (value === undefined) { // value is not in tree
                this.remove(key); // should not alter the tree
            } else { // value is in tree: update it
                map.set(key, value+10);
                this.set(key, value+10);
            }            
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of key/values in the array is the same as in the tree
            console.assert(isEqual(), "tree not same as array");
        }
        // Perform a series of deletions
        for (let i = map.size; i > 0; i--) {
            // Choose random deletion value
            let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i)
            let key = [...map.keys()][j];
            // Perform same deletion in array and tree
            map.delete(key);
            this.remove(key);
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of key/values in the array is the same as in the tree
            console.assert(isEqual(), "tree not same as array");
        }
    }
}

// Perform 1000 calls of set (some duplicates), 
//    1000 calls of get and updating set calls, 
//    and remove calls to remove all nodes,
//    on a tree with node capacity of 8
let tree = new Tree(8).test(1000);
console.log("all tests completed");
```

### Supported data types

The data type of the *keys* can be anything for which comparison operators work. So for strings or numbers it will work. In JavaScript it will also work for objects that have implemented either a `valueOf` or `toString` method. For instance, this is already the case for native `Date` objects. JavaScript will first try the `valueOf` method and in absence the `toString` method, which is also defined on the Object prototype.

### Considerations

Your decision to store one `key` in each node is fine for in-memory implementations, and I used that principle in this implementation. Historically, B(+)-trees are used for disk storage, where it is important to keep the number of block reads low. A standard B(+)-tree implementation stores the keys one level higher, in the parent, as an array. That way the search does not have to load each child record, while searching for the right one to choose.

Also, it then does not need to store the key of its first child, as we really only need the keys that *separate* two consecutive children.

Comment: How do you store an object for that key, I'm sorry that might not have been clear in my question. I would like to use this like a key/value store, or a hash table.

Comment: I guess this "key only" approach (no value) might work well for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645449/how-to-store-random-integers-from-the-set-of-32-bit-integers-in-a-compact-data-s/65648496)!

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the *value* (payload) part in your question. I will update it later.

Comment: I updated my answer to make it a key/value store.

Comment: how come this binary search starts at 1 with `low = 1`, rather than 0 like in a [generic abstracted binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55548615/169992)? Can you abstract this into a separate function so it calls into a generic binary search that will work in other situations? I have tried but not having any luck.

Comment: There are many ways to implement binary search. This one starts with `low = 1` because of the `>=` comparison. After the loop it performs `low--`. But this should work with any implementation of binary search. Just step through the code, and make sure the right item is selected by the search. If you cannot make it work, then I would suggest you would post a dedicated question just on the topic of a binary search implementation.