# How to optimally implement Stack and Queue operations in this B+tree?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, tree

In my learnings to understand B+trees I now would like to see what it takes to modify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65612476/169992) existing B+ index tree (which has the additional constraints of having every array be a power of 2 size in length: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32), and turn it into a Stack, and turn it into a Queue. Here is the original B+tree code from the wonderful linked answer:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(capacity) {
        // Mimic fixed-size array (avoid accidentally growing it)
        this.children = Object.seal(Array(capacity).fill(null));
        this.childCount = 0; // Number of used slots in children array
        this.treeSize = 0; // Total number of values in this subtree
        // Maintain back-link to parent.
        this.parent = null;
        // Per level in the tree, maintain a doubly linked list
        this.prev = this.next = null;
    }
    setCapacity(capacity) {
        if (capacity < 1) return;
        // Here we make a new array, and copy the data into it
        let children = Object.seal(Array(capacity).fill(null));
        for (let i = 0; i < this.childCount; i++) children[i] = this.children[i];
        this.children = children;
    }
    isLeaf() {
        return !(this.children[0] instanceof Node);
    }
    index() {
        return this.parent.children.indexOf(this);
    }
    updateTreeSize(start, end, sign=1) {        
        let sum = 0;
        if (this.isLeaf()) {
            sum = end - start;
        } else {
            for (let i = start; i < end; i++) sum += this.children[i].treeSize;
        }
        if (!sum) return;
        sum *= sign;
        // Apply the sum change to this node and all its ancestors
        for (let node = this; node; node = node.parent) {
            node.treeSize += sum;
        }
    }
    wipe(start, end) {
        this.updateTreeSize(start, end, -1);
        this.children.copyWithin(start, end, this.childCount);
        for (let i = this.childCount - end + start; i < this.childCount; i++) {
            this.children[i] = null;
        }
        this.childCount -= end - start;
        // Reduce allocated size if possible
        if (this.childCount * 2 <= this.children.length) this.setCapacity(this.children.length / 2);
    }
    moveFrom(neighbor, target, start, count=1) {
        // Note: `start` can have two meanings:
        //   if neighbor is null, it is the value/Node to move to the target
        //   if neighbor is a Node, it is the index from where value(s) have to be moved to the target
        // Make room in target node
        if (this.childCount + count > this.children.length) this.setCapacity(this.children.length * 2);
        this.children.copyWithin(target + count, target, Math.max(target + count, this.childCount));
        this.childCount += count;
        if (neighbor !== null) {
            // Copy the children
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                this.children[target + i] = neighbor.children[start + i];
            }
            // Remove the original references
            neighbor.wipe(start, start + count);
        } else {
            this.children[target] = start; // start is value to insert
        }
        this.updateTreeSize(target, target + count, 1);
        // Set parent link(s)
        if (!this.isLeaf()) {
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                this.children[target + i].parent = this;
            }
        }
    }
    moveToNext(count) {
        this.next.moveFrom(this, 0, this.childCount - count, count);
    }
    moveFromNext(count) {
        this.moveFrom(this.next, this.childCount, 0, count);
    }
    basicRemove(index) {
        if (!this.isLeaf()) {
            // Take node out of the level's linked list
            let prev = this.children[index].prev;
            let next = this.children[index].next;
            if (prev) prev.next = next;
            if (next) next.prev = prev;
        }
        this.wipe(index, index + 1);
    }
    basicInsert(index, value) {
        this.moveFrom(null, index, value);
        if (value instanceof Node) {
            // Insert node in the level's linked list
            if (index > 0) {
                value.prev = this.children[index-1];
                value.next = value.prev.next;
            } else if (this.childCount > 1) {
                value.next = this.children[1];
                value.prev = value.next.prev;
            }
            if (value.prev) value.prev.next = value;
            if (value.next) value.next.prev = value;
        }
    }
    pairWithSmallest() {            
        return this.prev && (!this.next || this.next.childCount > this.prev.childCount)
            ? [this.prev, this] : [this, this.next];
    }
    toString() {
        return "[" + this.children.map(v => v??"-").join() + "]";
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor(nodeCapacity=32) {
        this.nodeCapacity = nodeCapacity;
        this.root = new Node(1);
        this.first = this.root; // Head of doubly linked list at bottom level
    }
    locate(offset) {
        let node = this.root;
        // Normalise argument
        offset = offset < 0 ? Math.max(0, node.treeSize + offset) : Math.min(offset, node.treeSize);

        while (!node.isLeaf()) {
            let index = 0;
            let child = node.children[index];
            while (offset > child.treeSize || offset === child.treeSize && child.next) {
                offset -= child.treeSize;
                child = node.children[++index];
            }
            node = child;
        }
        return [node, offset];
    }
    getItemAt(offset) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index < node.childCount) return node.children[index];
    }
    setItemAt(offset, value) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index < node.childCount) node.children[index] = value;
    }
    removeItemAt(offset) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index >= node.childCount) return;

        while (true) {
            console.assert(node.isLeaf() || node.children[index].treeSize === 0);
            node.basicRemove(index);

            // Exit when node's fill ratio is fine
            if (!node.parent || node.childCount * 2 > this.nodeCapacity) return;
            // Node has potentially too few children, we should either merge or redistribute
            
            let [left, right] = node.pairWithSmallest();
            
            if (!left || !right) { // A node with no siblings? Must become the root!
                this.root = node;
                node.parent = null;
                return;
            }
            let sumCount = left.childCount + right.childCount;
            let childCount = sumCount >> 1;
            
            // Check whether to merge or to redistribute
            if (sumCount > this.nodeCapacity) { // redistribute
                // Move some data from the bigger to the smaller node
                let shift = childCount - node.childCount;
                if (!shift) { // Boundary case: when a redistribution would bring no improvement
                    console.assert(node.childCount * 2 === this.nodeCapacity && sumCount === this.nodeCapacity + 1);
                    return;
                }
                if (node === left) { // move some children from right to left
                    left.moveFromNext(shift);
                } else { // move some children from left to right
                    left.moveToNext(shift);
                }
                return;
            }
            
            // Merge:
            // Move all data from the right to the left
            left.moveFromNext(right.childCount);
            // Prepare to delete right node
            node = right.parent;
            index = right.index();
        }
    }
    insertItemAt(offset, value) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        while (node.childCount === this.nodeCapacity) { // No room here
            if (index === 0 && node.prev && node.prev.childCount < this.nodeCapacity) {
                return node.prev.basicInsert(node.prev.childCount, value);
            }
            // Check whether we can redistribute (to avoid a split)
            if (node !== this.root) {
                let [left, right] = node.pairWithSmallest();
                let joinedIndex = left === node ? index : left.childCount + index;
                let sumCount = left.childCount + right.childCount + 1;
                if (sumCount <= 2 * this.nodeCapacity) { // redistribute
                    let childCount = sumCount >> 1;
                    if (node === right) { // redistribute to the left
                        let insertInLeft = joinedIndex < childCount;
                        left.moveFromNext(childCount - left.childCount - +insertInLeft);
                    } else { // redistribute to the right
                        let insertInRight = index >= sumCount - childCount;
                        left.moveToNext(childCount - right.childCount - +insertInRight);
                    }
                    if (joinedIndex > left.childCount || 
                            joinedIndex === left.childCount && left.childCount > right.childCount) {
                        right.basicInsert(joinedIndex - left.childCount, value);
                    } else {
                        left.basicInsert(joinedIndex, value);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            // Cannot redistribute: split node
            let childCount = node.childCount >> 1;
            // Create a new node that will later become the right sibling of this node
            let sibling = new Node(childCount);
            // Move half of node node's data to it
            sibling.moveFrom(node, 0, childCount, childCount);
            // Insert the value in either the current node or the new one
            if (index > node.childCount) {
                sibling.basicInsert(index - node.childCount, value);
            } else {
                node.basicInsert(index, value);
            }
            // Is this the root? 
            if (!node.parent) {
                // ...then first create a parent, which is the new root
                this.root = new Node(2);
                this.root.basicInsert(0, node);
            }
            // Prepare for inserting the sibling node into the tree
            index = node.index() + 1;
            node = node.parent;
            value = sibling;
        }
        node.basicInsert(index, value);
    }
    /* Below this point: these methods are optional */
    * [Symbol.iterator]() { // Make tree iterable
        let i = 0;
        for (let node = this.first; node; node = node.next) {
            for (let i = 0; i < node.childCount; i++) yield node.children[i];
        }
    }
    print() {
        console.log(this.root && this.root.toString());
    }
    verify() {
        // Raise an error when the tree violates one of the required properties
        if (!this.root) return; // An empty tree is fine.
        if (this.root.parent) throw "root should not have a parent";
        // Perform a breadth first traversal
        let q = [this.root];
        while (q.length) {
            if (q[0].isLeaf() && this.first !== q[0]) throw "this.first is not pointing to first leaf";
            let level = [];
            let last = null;
            for (let parent of q) {
                if (!(parent instanceof Node)) throw "parent is not instance of Node";
                if (parent.children.length > this.nodeCapacity) throw "node's children array is too large";
                if (parent.childCount > 0 && parent.childCount * 2 <= parent.children.length) throw "node's fill ratio is too low";
                for (let i = parent.childCount; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
                    if (parent.children[i] !== null) throw "child beyond childCount should be null but is not";
                }
                let treeSize = parent.treeSize;
                if (parent.isLeaf()) {
                    for (let value of parent.children.slice(0, parent.childCount)) {
                        if (value === null) throw "leaf has a null as value";
                        if (value instanceof Node) throw "leaf has a Node as value";
                    }
                    if (parent.treeSize !== parent.childCount) throw "leaf has mismatch in treeSize and childCount";
                } else {
                    for (let node of parent.children.slice(0, parent.childCount)) {
                        if (node === null) throw "internal node has a null as value";
                        if (!(node instanceof Node)) throw "internal node has a non-Node as value";
                        if (node.parent !== parent) throw "wrong parent";
                        if (node.prev !== last) throw "prev link incorrect";
                        if (last && last.next !== node) throw "next link incorrect";
                        if (last && last.children.length + node.children.length <= this.nodeCapacity) {
                            throw "two consecutive siblings have a total number of children that is too small";
                        }
                        if (node.childCount * 2 < this.nodeCapacity) {
                            throw "internal node is too small: " + node;
                        }
                        level.push(node);
                        last = node;
                        treeSize -= node.treeSize;
                    }
                    if (treeSize) throw "internal node treeSize sum mismatches";
                }
            }
            if (last && last.next) throw "last node in level has a next reference";
            q = level;
        }
    }
    test(count=100, option=3) {
        // option:
        //     0 = always insert & delete at left side (offset 0)
        //     1 = always insert & delete at right side
        //     2 = always insert & delete at middle
        //     3 = insert & delete at random offsets
        // Create array to perform the same operations on it as on the tree
        let arr = [];
        // Perform a series of insertions
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // Choose random insertion index
            let index = Array.isArray(option) ? option[i] : [0, i, i >> 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1))][option];
            // Perform same insertion in array and tree
            arr.splice(index, 0, i);
            this.insertItemAt(index, i);
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of values in the array is the same as in the tree
            if (arr+"" !== [...this]+"") throw i + ": tree not same as array";
        }
        // Perform a series of updates
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // Choose random update index
            let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
            // Perform same insertion in array and tree
            arr[index] += count;
            this.setItemAt(index, this.getItemAt(index) + count);
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of values in the array is the same as in the tree
            if (arr+"" !== [...this]+"") throw "tree not same as array";
        }
        // Perform a series of deletions
        for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // Choose random deletion index
            let index = [0, i, i >> 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1))][option];
            // Perform same deletion in array and tree
            arr.splice(index, 1);
            this.removeItemAt(index);
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of values in the array is the same as in the tree
            if (arr+"" !== [...this]+"") throw "tree not same as array";
        }
    }
}

// Perform 1000 insertions, 1000 updates, and 1000 deletions on a tree with node capacity of 8
new Tree(8).test(1000);
console.log("all tests completed");
```

A stack is a last-in-first-out LIFO data structure, while a queue is a first-in-first-out FIFO one. A stack has a `push` and `pop` method (in addition to `getItemAt(index)` and other basic array methods, which this B+tree already implements). A queue has a `push` and `shift` method, where `shift` removes "from the front" of the array. So already they are similar, just add items to the end of the array, or remove from the start or end of the array.

The way I would do the `push` operation with the existing B+tree is to simply keep track of the length of the array (which you can do with `tree.root.treeSize`), and `insertItemAt(tree.root.treeSize, val)` it at that position. But maybe there is a more optimized way of doing this?

```
Tree.prototype.push = function(val) { this.insertItemAt(this.root.treeSize, val) }
```

For the pop, I would simply do:

```
Tree.prototype.pop = function() {
  let val = this.getItemAt(this.root.treeSize - 1)
  this.removeItemAt(this.root.treeSize - 1)
  return val
}
```

Finally, for the `shift`, I would do:

```
Tree.prototype.shift = function() {
  let val = this.getItemAt(0)
  this.removeItemAt(0)
  return val
}
```

But my question is, is there a better more optimized way to do this? Rather than traversing the whole tree to find the first or last item, maybe we could cache them? Not sure exactly the best approach here. What is the way to make this most optimal given the structure of the B+tree (as having these power of two constraints, that's pretty much it)? For example, on the "pluck" operations (pop and shift), there are *two traversals*, maybe this could be one (or none even)? How could this B+tree be modified to make these operations optimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my question is, is there a better more optimized way to do this? Rather than traversing the whole tree to find the first or last item, maybe we could cache them?

You could do some sort of caching. But do realise that "traversing the whole tree" is not as bad as it sounds. It is about traversing from the root to a leaf, so the number of node visits is equal to the number of levels. The number of levels of the tree is *O(logn)*. To get a tree with 10 levels, you would have to insert hundreds of billions of values.

Still, you can avoid that downward traversal by making use of the linked list that is maintained at the bottom level. The code already has a reference to the left most node in that list (`this.first`), and we could add a reference to the last one and keep it in sync.

Also, we could alter `removeItemAt` so that it also *returns* the deleted value. That way you don't have to do a separate call to `getItemAt`.

### The changes to make

To make `removeItemAt` return the removed value, add a line near the start of the function:

```
removeItemAt(offset) {
    let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
    if (index >= node.childCount) return;
    let value = node.children[index]; // <-- get deleted item (to return it)
```

... and change *each* of the 4 `return` statements to:

```
return value;
```

In the constructor, define `this.last`:

```
this.first = this.last = this.root; // Head & tail of doubly linked list at bottom level
```

...and potentially assign to it when inserting a node in `insertItemAt`:

```
let sibling = new Node(childCount);
if (node === this.last) this.last = sibling; // <----
```

...and assign to it when removing the last node in `removeItemAt` (near the end):

```
left.moveFromNext(right.childCount);
if (right === this.last) this.last = left; // <----
```

Then the `locate` method could detect a situation where the returned node should be either the first or last node in the bottom layer of the tree:

```
    // Normalise argument
    offset = offset < 0 ? Math.max(0, node.treeSize + offset) : Math.min(offset, node.treeSize);
    // Add these Shortcuts:
    if (offset < this.first.childCount) return [this.first, offset];
    if (offset >= node.treeSize - this.last.childCount) {
        return [this.last, offset - node.treeSize + this.last.childCount];
    }
```

Finally, we'll want to add these methods:

```
push(value) {
    this.insertItemAt(this.root.treeSize, value);
}
pop() {
    return this.removeItemAt(-1);
}
unshift(value) {
    this.insertItemAt(0, value);
}
shift() {
    return this.removeItemAt(0);
}
```

## Implementation - snippet

Here is the code with those changes, and the `test` method tailored to test these new methods:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(capacity) {
        // Mimic fixed-size array (avoid accidentally growing it)
        this.children = Object.seal(Array(capacity).fill(null));
        this.childCount = 0; // Number of used slots in children array
        this.treeSize = 0; // Total number of values in this subtree
        // Maintain back-link to parent.
        this.parent = null;
        // Per level in the tree, maintain a doubly linked list
        this.prev = this.next = null;
    }
    setCapacity(capacity) {
        if (capacity < 1) return;
        // Here we make a new array, and copy the data into it
        let children = Object.seal(Array(capacity).fill(null));
        for (let i = 0; i < this.childCount; i++) children[i] = this.children[i];
        this.children = children;
    }
    isLeaf() {
        return !(this.children[0] instanceof Node);
    }
    index() {
        return this.parent.children.indexOf(this);
    }
    updateTreeSize(start, end, sign=1) {        
        let sum = 0;
        if (this.isLeaf()) {
            sum = end - start;
        } else {
            for (let i = start; i < end; i++) sum += this.children[i].treeSize;
        }
        if (!sum) return;
        sum *= sign;
        // Apply the sum change to this node and all its ancestors
        for (let node = this; node; node = node.parent) {
            node.treeSize += sum;
        }
    }
    wipe(start, end) {
        this.updateTreeSize(start, end, -1);
        this.children.copyWithin(start, end, this.childCount);
        for (let i = this.childCount - end + start; i < this.childCount; i++) {
            this.children[i] = null;
        }
        this.childCount -= end - start;
        // Reduce allocated size if possible
        if (this.childCount * 2 <= this.children.length) this.setCapacity(this.children.length / 2);
    }
    moveFrom(neighbor, target, start, count=1) {
        // Note: `start` can have two meanings:
        //   if neighbor is null, it is the value/Node to move to the target
        //   if neighbor is a Node, it is the index from where value(s) have to be moved to the target
        // Make room in target node
        if (this.childCount + count > this.children.length) this.setCapacity(this.children.length * 2);
        this.children.copyWithin(target + count, target, Math.max(target + count, this.childCount));
        this.childCount += count;
        if (neighbor !== null) {
            // Copy the children
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                this.children[target + i] = neighbor.children[start + i];
            }
            // Remove the original references
            neighbor.wipe(start, start + count);
        } else {
            this.children[target] = start; // start is value to insert
        }
        this.updateTreeSize(target, target + count, 1);
        // Set parent link(s)
        if (!this.isLeaf()) {
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                this.children[target + i].parent = this;
            }
        }
    }
    moveToNext(count) {
        this.next.moveFrom(this, 0, this.childCount - count, count);
    }
    moveFromNext(count) {
        this.moveFrom(this.next, this.childCount, 0, count);
    }
    basicRemove(index) {
        if (!this.isLeaf()) {
            // Take node out of the level's linked list
            let prev = this.children[index].prev;
            let next = this.children[index].next;
            if (prev) prev.next = next;
            if (next) next.prev = prev;
        }
        this.wipe(index, index + 1);
    }
    basicInsert(index, value) {
        this.moveFrom(null, index, value);
        if (value instanceof Node) {
            // Insert node in the level's linked list
            if (index > 0) {
                value.prev = this.children[index-1];
                value.next = value.prev.next;
            } else if (this.childCount > 1) {
                value.next = this.children[1];
                value.prev = value.next.prev;
            }
            if (value.prev) value.prev.next = value;
            if (value.next) value.next.prev = value;
        }
    }
    pairWithSmallest() {            
        return this.prev && (!this.next || this.next.childCount > this.prev.childCount)
            ? [this.prev, this] : [this, this.next];
    }
    toString() {
        return "[" + this.children.map(v => v??"-").join() + "]";
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor(nodeCapacity=32) {
        this.nodeCapacity = nodeCapacity;
        this.root = new Node(1);
        this.first = this.last = this.root; // Head of doubly linked list at bottom level
    }
    locate(offset) {
        let node = this.root;
        // Normalise argument
        offset = offset < 0 ? Math.max(0, node.treeSize + offset) : Math.min(offset, node.treeSize);
        // Shortcuts
        
        if (offset < this.first.childCount) return [this.first, offset]; // *
        if (offset >= node.treeSize - this.last.childCount) {
            return [this.last, offset - node.treeSize + this.last.childCount]; // *
        }
        while (!node.isLeaf()) {
            let index = 0;
            let child = node.children[index];
            while (offset > child.treeSize || offset === child.treeSize && child.next) {
                offset -= child.treeSize;
                child = node.children[++index];
            }
            node = child;
        }
        return [node, offset];
    }
    getItemAt(offset) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index < node.childCount) return node.children[index];
    }
    setItemAt(offset, value) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index < node.childCount) node.children[index] = value;
    }
    removeItemAt(offset) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        if (index >= node.childCount) return;
        let value = node.children[index]; // * get deleted item (to return it)
        
        while (true) {
            console.assert(node.isLeaf() || node.children[index].treeSize === 0);
            node.basicRemove(index);

            // Exit when node's fill ratio is fine
            if (!node.parent || node.childCount * 2 > this.nodeCapacity) return value; // *
            // Node has potentially too few children, we should either merge or redistribute
            
            let [left, right] = node.pairWithSmallest();
            
            if (!left || !right) { // A node with no siblings? Must become the root!
                this.root = node;
                node.parent = null;
                return value; // *
            }
            let sumCount = left.childCount + right.childCount;
            let childCount = sumCount >> 1;
            
            // Check whether to merge or to redistribute
            if (sumCount > this.nodeCapacity) { // redistribute
                // Move some data from the bigger to the smaller node
                let shift = childCount - node.childCount;
                if (!shift) { // Boundary case: when a redistribution would bring no improvement
                    console.assert(node.childCount * 2 === this.nodeCapacity && sumCount === this.nodeCapacity + 1);
                    return value; // *
                }
                if (node === left) { // move some children from right to left
                    left.moveFromNext(shift);
                } else { // move some children from left to right
                    left.moveToNext(shift);
                }
                return value; // *
            }
            
            // Merge:
            // Move all data from the right to the left
            left.moveFromNext(right.childCount);
            if (right === this.last) this.last = left;
            // Prepare to delete right node
            node = right.parent;
            index = right.index();
        }
    }
    insertItemAt(offset, value) {
        let [node, index] = this.locate(offset);
        while (node.childCount === this.nodeCapacity) { // No room here
            if (index === 0 && node.prev && node.prev.childCount < this.nodeCapacity) {
                return node.prev.basicInsert(node.prev.childCount, value);
            }
            // Check whether we can redistribute (to avoid a split)
            if (node !== this.root) {
                let [left, right] = node.pairWithSmallest();
                let joinedIndex = left === node ? index : left.childCount + index;
                let sumCount = left.childCount + right.childCount + 1;
                if (sumCount <= 2 * this.nodeCapacity) { // redistribute
                    let childCount = sumCount >> 1;
                    if (node === right) { // redistribute to the left
                        let insertInLeft = joinedIndex < childCount;
                        left.moveFromNext(childCount - left.childCount - +insertInLeft);
                    } else { // redistribute to the right
                        let insertInRight = index >= sumCount - childCount;
                        left.moveToNext(childCount - right.childCount - +insertInRight);
                    }
                    if (joinedIndex > left.childCount || 
                            joinedIndex === left.childCount && left.childCount > right.childCount) {
                        right.basicInsert(joinedIndex - left.childCount, value);
                    } else {
                        left.basicInsert(joinedIndex, value);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            // Cannot redistribute: split node
            let childCount = node.childCount >> 1;
            // Create a new node that will later become the right sibling of this node
            let sibling = new Node(childCount);
            if (node === this.last) this.last = sibling;
            // Move half of node node's data to it
            sibling.moveFrom(node, 0, childCount, childCount);
            // Insert the value in either the current node or the new one
            if (index > node.childCount) {
                sibling.basicInsert(index - node.childCount, value);
            } else {
                node.basicInsert(index, value);
            }
            // Is this the root? 
            if (!node.parent) {
                // ...then first create a parent, which is the new root
                this.root = new Node(2);
                this.root.basicInsert(0, node);
            }
            // Prepare for inserting the sibling node into the tree
            index = node.index() + 1;
            node = node.parent;
            value = sibling;
        }
        node.basicInsert(index, value);
    }
    // * added 4 methods
    push(value) {
        this.insertItemAt(this.root.treeSize, value);
    }
    pop() {
        return this.removeItemAt(-1);
    }
    unshift(value) {
        this.insertItemAt(0, value);
    }
    shift() {
        return this.removeItemAt(0);
    }
    /* Below this point: these methods are optional */
    * [Symbol.iterator]() { // Make tree iterable
        let i = 0;
        for (let node = this.first; node; node = node.next) {
            for (let i = 0; i < node.childCount; i++) yield node.children[i];
        }
    }
    print() {
        console.log(this.root && this.root.toString());
    }
    verify() {
        // Raise an error when the tree violates one of the required properties
        if (!this.root) return; // An empty tree is fine.
        if (this.root.parent) throw "root should not have a parent";
        // Perform a breadth first traversal
        let q = [this.root];
        while (q.length) {
            if (q[0].isLeaf() && this.first !== q[0]) throw "this.first is not pointing to first leaf";
            let level = [];
            let last = null;
            for (let parent of q) {
                if (!(parent instanceof Node)) throw "parent is not instance of Node";
                if (parent.children.length > this.nodeCapacity) throw "node's children array is too large";
                if (parent.childCount > 0 && parent.childCount * 2 <= parent.children.length) throw "node's fill ratio is too low";
                for (let i = parent.childCount; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
                    if (parent.children[i] !== null) throw "child beyond childCount should be null but is not";
                }
                let treeSize = parent.treeSize;
                if (parent.isLeaf()) {
                    for (let value of parent.children.slice(0, parent.childCount)) {
                        if (value === null) throw "leaf has a null as value";
                        if (value instanceof Node) throw "leaf has a Node as value";
                    }
                    if (parent.treeSize !== parent.childCount) throw "leaf has mismatch in treeSize and childCount";
                } else {
                    for (let node of parent.children.slice(0, parent.childCount)) {
                        if (node === null) throw "internal node has a null as value";
                        if (!(node instanceof Node)) throw "internal node has a non-Node as value";
                        if (node.parent !== parent) throw "wrong parent";
                        if (node.prev !== last) throw "prev link incorrect";
                        if (last && last.next !== node) throw "next link incorrect";
                        if (last && last.children.length + node.children.length <= this.nodeCapacity) {
                            throw "two consecutive siblings have a total number of children that is too small";
                        }
                        if (node.childCount * 2 < this.nodeCapacity) {
                            throw "internal node is too small: " + node;
                        }
                        level.push(node);
                        last = node;
                        treeSize -= node.treeSize;
                    }
                    if (treeSize) throw "internal node treeSize sum mismatches";
                }
            }
            if (last && last.next) throw "last node in level has a next reference";
            q = level;
        }
    }
    test(count=100, option=3) {
        // option:
        //     0 = always insert & delete at left side (offset 0)
        //     1 = always insert & delete at right side
        //     2 = always insert & delete at middle
        //     3 = insert & delete at random offsets
        // Create array to perform the same operations on it as on the tree
        let arr = [];
        // Perform a series of insertions
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // Choose random insertion index
            let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
            // Perform same insertion in array and tree
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                arr.push(i);
                this.push(i);
            } else {
                arr.unshift(i);
                this.unshift(i);
            }
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of values in the array is the same as in the tree
            if (arr+"" !== [...this]+"") throw i + ": tree not same as array";
        }
        // Perform a series of deletions and insertions
        for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // Choose random deletion index
            let index = [0, i, i >> 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1))][option];
            // Perform same deletion in array and tree
            if (Math.random() < 0.6) {
                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    if (arr.pop(i) !== this.pop(i)) throw "pop returns different value";
                } else {
                    if (arr.shift(i) !== this.shift(i)) throw "shift returns different value";
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    arr.push(i);
                    this.push(i);
                } else {
                    arr.unshift(i);
                    this.unshift(i);
                }
            }
            // Verify tree consistency and properties
            this.verify();
            // Verify the order of values in the array is the same as in the tree
            if (arr+"" !== [...this]+"") throw "tree not same as array";
        }
        return this;
    }
}

// Perform 1000 insertions, with either push or unshift, 
// then a mix of 1000 insertions/removals, the latter with either pop or shift.
new Tree(8).test(1000);
console.log("all tests completed");
```